# Vim Encoding is not working on Mongolian text

Tags: vim

Vim is not opening Mongolian text properly

When I do head -5 file.txt I get the following

```
Ямар нөхцөлд амьжиргааны түвшний үнэлгээнд дахин орох вэ Ийм тохиолдол байж болох ажээ. +++++SEP+++++ What is the case with living standards?
Уг аяны үргэлжлэл болгож "Бид хамтдаа" үндэсний форумыг ирэх долоо хоногт зохион байгуулахаар болжээ. +++++SEP+++++ As part of the campaign, we will organize a national forum next week.
Алтан гахай жилийн 25 хувийн илүү төрөлт өнөөдөр нийгэмд ачаалал болж орж ирж байгаа. +++++SEP+++++ The 25-year-old birth of the Golden Pig is a burden on society today.
Уг нь Н.Алтанхуяг гэх хүн авлигал, албан тушаалын хэрэгт холбогдвол АТГ чиг, үүргийнхээ дагуу шалгаж, нягтлах ёстой. +++++SEP+++++ If the person, N.Altankhuyag, is involved in corrupt or official affairs, the IAAC should check and examine it accordingly.
Азийн арлын энэ жижиг улс долоон жил дараалан уг жагсаалтыг тэргүүлж байгаа юм. +++++SEP+++++ The small island of Asia is the leader of the list for the seven consecutive years.
```

and when I open the same file with vim I get the following

```
Ð¯Ð¼Ð°Ñ<80> Ð½Ó©Ñ<85>Ñ<86>Ó©Ð»Ð´ Ð°Ð¼Ñ<8c>Ð¶Ð¸Ñ<80>Ð³Ð°Ð°Ð½Ñ<8b> Ñ<82>Ò¯Ð²Ñ<88>Ð½Ð¸Ð¹ Ò¯Ð½Ñ<8d>Ð»Ð³Ñ<8d>Ñ<8d>Ð½Ð´ Ð´Ð°Ñ<85>Ð¸Ð½ Ð¾Ñ<80>Ð¾Ñ<85> Ð²Ñ<8d> Ð<98>Ð¹Ð¼ Ñ<82>Ð¾Ñ<85>Ð¸Ð¾Ð»Ð´Ð¾Ð» Ð±Ð°Ð¹Ð¶ Ð±Ð¾Ð»Ð¾Ñ<85> Ð°Ð¶Ñ<8d>Ñ<8d>. +++++SEP+++++ What is the case with living standards?
Ð£Ð³ Ð°Ñ<8f>Ð½Ñ<8b> Ò¯Ñ<80>Ð³Ñ<8d>Ð»Ð¶Ð»Ñ<8d>Ð» Ð±Ð¾Ð»Ð³Ð¾Ð¶ "Ð<91>Ð¸Ð´ Ñ<85>Ð°Ð¼Ñ<82>Ð´Ð°Ð°" Ò¯Ð½Ð´Ñ<8d>Ñ<81>Ð½Ð¸Ð¹ Ñ<84>Ð¾Ñ<80>Ñ<83>Ð¼Ñ<8b>Ð³ Ð¸Ñ<80>Ñ<8d>Ñ<85> Ð´Ð¾Ð»Ð¾Ð¾ Ñ<85>Ð¾Ð½Ð¾Ð³Ñ<82> Ð·Ð¾Ñ<85>Ð¸Ð¾Ð½ Ð±Ð°Ð¹Ð³Ñ<83>Ñ<83>Ð»Ð°Ñ<85>Ð°Ð°Ñ<80> Ð±Ð¾Ð»Ð¶Ñ<8d>Ñ<8d>. +++++SEP+++++ As part of the campaign, we will organize a national forum next week.
Ð<90>Ð»Ñ<82>Ð°Ð½ Ð³Ð°Ñ<85>Ð°Ð¹ Ð¶Ð¸Ð»Ð¸Ð¹Ð½ 25 Ñ<85>Ñ<83>Ð²Ð¸Ð¹Ð½ Ð¸Ð»Ò¯Ò¯ Ñ<82>Ó©Ñ<80>Ó©Ð»Ñ<82> Ó©Ð½Ó©Ó©Ð´Ó©Ñ<80> Ð½Ð¸Ð¹Ð³Ñ<8d>Ð¼Ð´ Ð°Ñ<87>Ð°Ð°Ð»Ð°Ð» Ð±Ð¾Ð»Ð¶ Ð¾Ñ<80>Ð¶ Ð¸Ñ<80>Ð¶ Ð±Ð°Ð¹Ð³Ð°Ð°. +++++SEP+++++ The 25-year-old birth of the Golden Pig is a burden on society today.
Ð£Ð³ Ð½Ñ<8c> Ð<9d>.Ð<90>Ð»Ñ<82>Ð°Ð½Ñ<85>Ñ<83>Ñ<8f>Ð³ Ð³Ñ<8d>Ñ<85> Ñ<85>Ò¯Ð½ Ð°Ð²Ð»Ð¸Ð³Ð°Ð», Ð°Ð»Ð±Ð°Ð½ Ñ<82>Ñ<83>Ñ<88>Ð°Ð°Ð»Ñ<8b>Ð½ Ñ<85>Ñ<8d>Ñ<80>Ñ<8d>Ð³Ñ<82> Ñ<85>Ð¾Ð»Ð±Ð¾Ð³Ð´Ð²Ð¾Ð» Ð<90>Ð¢Ð<93> Ñ<87>Ð¸Ð³, Ò¯Ò¯Ñ<80>Ð³Ð¸Ð¹Ð½Ñ<85>Ñ<8d>Ñ<8d> Ð´Ð°Ð³Ñ<83>Ñ<83> Ñ<88>Ð°Ð»Ð³Ð°Ð¶, Ð½Ñ<8f>Ð³Ñ<82>Ð»Ð°Ñ<85> Ñ<91>Ñ<81>Ñ<82>Ð¾Ð¹. +++++SEP+++++ If the person, N.Altankhuyag, is involved in corrupt or official affairs, the IAAC should check and examine it accordingly.
Ð<90>Ð·Ð¸Ð¹Ð½ Ð°Ñ<80>Ð»Ñ<8b>Ð½ Ñ<8d>Ð½Ñ<8d> Ð¶Ð¸Ð¶Ð¸Ð³ Ñ<83>Ð»Ñ<81> Ð´Ð¾Ð»Ð¾Ð¾Ð½ Ð¶Ð¸Ð» Ð´Ð°Ñ<80>Ð°Ð°Ð»Ð°Ð½ Ñ<83>Ð³ Ð¶Ð°Ð³Ñ<81>Ð°Ð°Ð»Ñ<82>Ñ<8b>Ð³ Ñ<82>Ñ<8d>Ñ<80>Ð³Ò¯Ò¯Ð»Ð¶ Ð±Ð°Ð¹Ð³Ð°Ð° Ñ<8e>Ð¼. +++++SEP+++++ The small island of Asia is the leader of the list for the seven consecutive years.
```

How do I see the text in vim so it doesn't show me these weird characters.

Comment: `set encoding? fileencodings?`

Comment: You should try to `set encoding=utf-8` and `set termencoding=utf-8`. See `:h encoding` and `:h encoding-names`. If you are using vim under GNU/Linux it should already be like this.

Comment: Another thing to look at is the font your terminal is using, it may not supply the mongolian characters.